# Dictionary Keys (List<int>) Retrieve in C#

Tags: dictionary, c#-2.0

Assumed I defined my dict as below.

`Dictionary<list<int>, list<string>> d = new Dictionary<List<int>, list<string>>()`

How can I retrieve the dict key and value rapidly.

[update]

I want to get the Key - List content.
I tried a simple way as below

`List<int> KeysList= new List<int>(d.Keys);`

But it doesn't work at the complex key on my case.

Can I only use the `KeyValuePair` as below?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<List<int>, List<string>> pair in d)
{
     KeysList= new List<int>(pair.Key);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by rapidly? And what are you trying to access?

Comment: @erash. I updated my rapidly way. like the simple way of `d.keys`

Comment: Is it possible you're looking for `Dictionary<int, string>`? That'd make the last line `List<int> KeysList = d.Keys;`.

Comment: @Kobi, No. Actually I am looking for `List<int>` as the `KeysList` (assumed there are one Key collected some items of List<int> and one value collected some items of List<string>)

Comment: Oh, Ok. Can you please add example of such a dictionary (e.g. Keys are `{1}, {1,2,3}, {20, 30, 1, 1}`), and an example of the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a potential problem there to start with: `List<T>` doesn't override Equals, so you'd have to use the *exact* same key reference to fetch the value for a key.

Having said that, if you *have* that reference, it's as simple as

```
List<string> value = d[key];
```

or

```
List<string> value;
if (d.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    ...
}
```

It's pretty unusual to have a `List<T>` as a key though - can you tell us more about what you're trying to do? There may be a better approach.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the first point - what do you mean by *"exact same key reference"*? Wouldn't it work with two references to the same list, or with references from `Dictionary.Keys`?

Comment: I can't try `List<string> value = d[key];`. It doesn't work on my case. It's a function call, I don't know the Key exactly. BTW, I updated my input above.

Comment: @Nano: Your question still isn't clear at all. You talk about "the" `List<int>` but the point of a dictionary is that *each key* is a `List<int>`. Which one are you interested in? If you could provide a short but *complete* example of what you're talking about, it would be a lot easier to help you.